# Emulator errors after upgrade to Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I upgraded to Android Studio 1.4 yesterday and since then I have been having problems running any emulators.

I have also recently upgraded to El Capitan and  am trying to work out if it is Android Studio, El Capitan or something I did with my set up.

```
emulator: WARNING: .//android/metrics/metrics_reporter_ga.c:138: curl_easy_perform() failed with code 7 (Error)
emulator: WARNING: .//android/metrics/metrics_reporter_ga.c:145: Got HTTP response code 0
emulator: WARNING: .//android/metrics/metrics_reporter_toolbar.c:92: curl_easy_perform() failed with code 28 (Error)
emulator: WARNING: .//android/metrics/metrics_reporter_toolbar.c:100: Got HTTP response code 0
```

After I get these warnings, the emulator restarts itself and runs as normal.

Comment: Some times, I noticed that the emulator tries to upload usage metrics to google. When my workstation is behind a proxy and the emulator tries to upload such information, it doesn't use the system's proxy config neither emulator's proxy parameter information. In order to circumvent this "bug", I just switch off the networking at the moment that the android emulator is booting. After that, I switch on the networking and everything works as expected

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug and the issue has just been raised here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196524

Comment: Cheers, I've starred it

Answer (score 0):

I also upgraded to 1.4, and emulator startup time is much more longer, now is similar to emulator without host GPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

I just find a workaround. Hope it works for you:
Open the Android Studio->Preferences, go to Appearance & Behavior->System Settings->Usage Statistics, and uncheck "Send usage statistics to Google".
Now the matrics_reporter will be disabled during emulator starting.